# Vanishing text for php scrape/output data with javascript and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide

So, I'm successfully doing something where I have an animation at start of loading page, and everything behind the animation is black. Once the animation is done loading, all the white text then appears.

I'm doing this with a function that changes the color of the text. For ex, I have a black background, and I tell the text to be black, but once animation is done, I tell it to turn white, or green. Thus hidden when animation is going on, visible after.

I have an issue though with the way I found this example, it directs the html by using a

```
<p class="appear-later">
```

However, this is causing me issues. I need to find another way of defining text to change in this way, without using the p class. As you can see below, I have various php outputted data, but it seems to cancel the P function, every time a new PHP is called forth. Now, I could just keep repeating the

```
 <p class="appear-later">
```

For every line of text, but this causes a further issue, by breaking up the code into different vertical lines. Not good.

So I'm wondering if there's another way of basically telling the html that everything below this tag, until the tag is ended, apply the text effect. I know there is, I'm just bad at programming. Thanks for thoughts! Something besides a p class. A way to re write that html code without having to make it a p class that wouldn't cause such issues with the php outputs

Here's the code

```
<div id="ethereum">
<div class="mainheader">
<p class="appear-later">Price of Ethereum
</div>
<?php outputValueFromCache("ethereumvalue", "ignore");?>
&nbsp;
[
<?php outputValueFromCache("ethereumchange");?>
]
</p>
</div>



.appear-later { color: black; }

setTimeout(function () {
$('.appear-later').removeClass('appear-later');
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to apply css to all child elements of the `<p class="appear-later">` then use *, as such

```
.appear-later * {
    color: black; 
}
```

Although I suggest making that `<p>` into a `<div>` and then have your child elements there. Here is a fiddle to use as example.
https://jsfiddle.net/Arparas/wunjgqo0/
 I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: very helpful thank you! That worked, can I ask, what does putting the   *   in the CSS do? Never seen that before. Secondly, this works in almost all situations, except here. I'm wondering if there's some conflict with the php that's making it do this. The first php reference, has some extra code that ignores some paramters in the global php. Wonder if that's why, or if you have any ideas how to deal with that. I guess it's more of a php issue though.

Comment: <div class="appear-later">
<div class="mainheader">
<p>DOW</p>
</div>
<?php outputValueFromCache("dowcurrent", "ignore");?>
&nbsp;
<?php outputValueFromCache('dowdailychange');?>
&nbsp;
<?php outputValueFromCache('dowpercentchange');?>
</div>

Comment: I'm glad that helped, the * is used to select all elements in a document, when the selector is used by it self, ex `* {  }`, when used in front of another element selector, like I had shown, it selects all child elements of that element. As for your php problem, I'm sorry but I do not know php well enough to help you there.